Show number of references for a function
In this website I notice that in the screenshot they provided has the number of reference at which the function is called throughout the project. Does anyone know which extension provides this feature?

I have no idea why but in my VS Code (latest version), the used functions and unused functions have the same font color (as in the image below), which is very confusing. I am using Material Theme Palenight High Contrast. I tried reinstalling VS Code and remove all its extension and user data, then reinstall again but to no avail.


in your vscode settings search for "typescript references". There you can enable References Code Lens
